# Wrong total cost value being obtained

Tags: c++, casting, double

> Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal, find and print the meal's total cost.

Here is my code:

```
void solve(double meal_cost, double tip_percent, double tax_percent) {

    double total;
    tip_percent=meal_cost*((tip_percent)/100.0);
    tax_percent=((tax_percent)/100.0)*meal_cost;
    total=(meal_cost)+(tip_percent)+(tax_percent);
    int t1=(double)total ;
    cout<<t1;
}
```

This is FAILING against these test case values, respectively:

> 10.25
>   17
>   5

Expected Output:

> 13

The code had passed 3 test cases, but failed in the last test case having the above mentioned values (so I'm doubtful if the calculation of the tip is wrong or not).

I think it's an issue of rounding off. How do I handle that?

NO CHANGE REFLECTED :  `cout<<round(t1);`, I rounded off the value but still no change.

Comment: What does it print out and what does the test expect it to print out?

Comment: Why are you storing the result as `int` before printing it? What if the correct result is not an integer? Also, the assignment isn't very clear on whether tip should be based on the base amount or after-tax. (And I guess the other way around would also be possible.)

Comment: @walnut - most gratuities are computed "pre-tax".  But yeah, this question needs more clarity.

Comment: If this question isn't amended to discuss the expected inputs and outputs within the next few minutes, I'm going to vote to close it.

Comment: @selbie Depends on where you live. Where I am tips are usually based on after-tax prices.

Comment: I have updated the expected output,I dont know my output ,all it displays is "Wrong Answer"

Comment: Expected output is 13

Comment: @selbie So do you think I should calculate the tips on the basis of after tax prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your formula corresponds to the local practices of your country (here tip and tax calculated individually, so no tax on the tip, and the tip is not calculated on the taxed meal cost)

The problem is that your `total` is defined as `int`. So it's truncated. And you were very lucky with your first test cases ;-)

This should already improve the situation:

```
double t1=total ;
```

However, this will lead to a three digit value, `12.505`.  With  `<iomanip>` you could format better:

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<t1;   // 12.50
```

If you don't want two digits,  you could just let the formatting do the job:

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<t1;   // 13
```

But it could be a better idea to control [rounding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) at the level ove the calculation using some `<cmath>` function:

```
double t1=round(total) ;
```

**Not related:** Finally, it's just an exercise,  but I'd nevertheless recommened that you'd consider returning the value from your function and printing the value elesewhere.  This would follow the principle that one function should do one thing and do it well.